# Matplotlib error plotting interval bins for discretized values form pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

An error is returned when I want to plot an interval.
I created an interval for my age column so now I want to show on a chart the age interval compares to the revenue

my code

```
bins = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]
clients['tranche'] = pd.cut(clients.age, bins)
clients.head()

    client_id   sales       revenue         birth       age     sex     tranche
0   c_1         39          558.18          1955        66      m       (60, 70]
1   c_10        58          1353.60         1956        65      m       (60, 70]
2   c_100       8           254.85          1992        29      m       (20, 30]
3   c_1000      125         2261.89         1966        55      f       (50, 60]
4   c_1001      102         1812.86         1982        39      m       (30, 40]
    
# Plot a scatter tranche x revenue
df = clients.groupby('tranche')[['revenue']].sum().reset_index().copy()
plt.scatter(df.tranche, df.revenue)
plt.show()
```

But an error appears ending by

```
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'pandas._libs.interval.Interval'
```

How to use an interval for plotting ?

Comment: Hey, for easy reproducible can please prove some sample data as well? you can run `clients.head().to_dict()` and past the output into a code block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to add labels. (i tried to convert them to str using `.astype(str)` but that does not seem to work in 3.9)

if you do the following, it will work just fine.

```
labels = ['10-20', '20-30', '30-40']
df['tranche'] = pd.cut(df.age, bins, labels=labels)
```